# Optimal way to extract string in redshift without using regexp

Tags: sql, regex, string, substring, amazon-redshift

Lets say we want to extract the substring from url till second occurrence of `/`.

e.g. 
`https://abc.def.com/abc?102/` extracted string should be `abc.def.com/abc` without `?102`

`http://abc.def/jkl/ghi/` extracted string should be `abc.def/jkl`

I want to achieve this without using `regexp_substr/regexp_replace`, which I have already tried.

Comment: Why do you specifically want to avoid regexp functions?

Comment: My observation: REGEXP is quite costly, suppose there is a large table of worth 100+ GB then it will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to avoid regexes, you could use `split_part()` twice:

```
select split_part(url, '/', 1) || '/' || split_part(url, '/', 2)
```

I am unsure, however, that this would perform better than a regex-based solution. You would need to benchmark this against your real dataset.

Comment: @SayedAweshRahman: as explained in my answer, it is hard to tell beforehand. You would probably need to test it (I'd be actually interested to know which solution performs better).

Comment: Using REGEXP is actually very costly where I benchmarked with 20M rows:
REGEXP took 12 mins 30 Sec
Where as SPLIT_PART just took 2 min 09 seconds to give the result